# Represent an ID code in regex

Tags: regex, string

I just learned about regex couple of days ago , and would like to expand my knowledge a bit , I would like to match an id code that has the letter A as the first letter and the second letter may be a letter or integer . The ID_code has to be 2 letters long .

```
A{“A”-“Z”|”0”-“9”}  This is a general representation of what I trying to achieve,
```

so far I got the second letter. now I need to match the first letter A and the second letter in case it's a number .

```
String.matches("-?[A-Z]+")
```

This is not for a homework or grade btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. My favourite is `A[a-zA-Z0-9]` because I think this is the most readable way of managing it, though `A[\d\w]` is quite graceful too.

Comment: yep the first one worked can't believe I was that close to the answer also I had to remove the + because if not the ID_CODE may be more than the two numbers I wanted . Thanks .